# Proverb or expression for a situation with two choices, both leading to a different kind of trouble

Tags: expressions, proverbs

I'm searching for a proverb or expression that describes a situation which has two choices or two ways out (that is, somewhat of a forced choice) where both lead to some kind of trouble (but not the same trouble).

As an example: Let's say that you can chose to go either left or right. If you go left, you will have to fight your way through an army of trolls. If you go right, you will have to go through a desert without any food or water for one week.

Comment: It's off-topic, but I can't refrain...: in Italian it is: "*Dalla padella alla brace*" :-)

Comment: "If I go there will be trouble, an' if I stay it will be double" - The Clash

Comment: @Marco What does it literally mean? In swedish, it is called to "sitta i en rävsax" which translates to "sitting in a fox trap". I think it's one of those traps which snaps shut and therefore you encounter troubles from both sides at the same time.

Comment: Dilemna? Paradox?

Comment: I thought of *double edged sword* besides a few that are already here.

Comment: "Choisir entre la peste et le choléra" :)

Comment: As a UK English speaker, referring to the situation I'd say I was "between a rock and a hard place", while referring to the choices themselves I would say my choice was between "the lesser of two evils".

Comment: Two choices, each one worse than the other.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The most common English phrase for this is [*between a rock and a hard place*](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/between-a-rock-and-a-hard-place.html). It means:

> In difficulty, faced with a choice between two unsatisfactory options.

Specifically, to say you are *caught between a rock and a hard place* means that you are in a dilemma. The exact dilemma seems to be exactly what you're describing--[Morton's fork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton%27s_fork), which is:

> a choice between two equally unpleasant alternatives (in other words, a dilemma), or two lines of reasoning that lead to the same unpleasant conclusion. It is analogous to the expressions "between the devil and the deep blue sea," "between a rock and a hard place," or, as those in the Spanish- and Portuguese-speaking world say, "Between a cross and a sword." This is the opposite of the Buridan's Ass.

Comment: Let's not forget a good old one:  Damned if you do; damned if you don't.

Comment: NB The Spanish set phrase is actually "between a sword and a wall" (literally "the" rather than "a").

Comment: Between the horns of a dilemma.

Comment: @simchona +1 You deserve being a Guru :)

Answer (score 31):

There are a number of these in English.

> Between a rock and a hard place.
>
> Between Scylla and Charybdis.
>
> Between the devil and the deep blue sea.

As well as the closely related expression:

> Out of the frying pan and into the fire.

Comment: "Between a rock and a hard place." is a nice one, but "Out of the frying pan and into the fire." actually means you went _from a bad situation to a worse one_.

Comment: I was proud I understood the expression "between Scylla and Charybdis" when I first heard it.

Comment: @jhocking Can you explain it? :)

Comment: They are a couple of sea monsters that guarded a waterway in ancient Greek myth.

Comment: @LouisRhys: In Greek mythology, Scylla was a sea monster who lived underneath a dangerous rock at one side of the Strait of Messina, opposite the whirlpool Charybdis.She threatened passing ships and in the Odyssey ate six of Odysseus' companions. Charybdis was once a nymph-daughter of Poseidon and Gaia who flooded lands for her father's underwater kingdom until Zeus turned her into a monster and have her suck in and out water three times an day. She lived in a cave at one side of the Strait of Messina, opposite the monster Scylla, the two of them forming a dangerous threat to passing ships.

Answer (score 12):

Although you asked for a proverb or expression (which **simchona** has provided), there's also a single word for this: a *dilemma* is a choice between equally unappealing options. From the Oxford English Dictionary:

> **1.** In *Rhetoric*. A form of argument involving an adversary in the choice of two (or, loosely, more) alternatives, either of which is (or appears) equally unfavourable to him. (The alternatives are commonly spoken of as the ‘horns’ of the dilemma.) Hence in Logic, a hypothetical syllogism having a conjunctive or ‘conditional’ major premiss and a disjunctive minor (or, one premiss conjunctive and the other disjunctive).
>
> **2.** Hence, in popular use: A choice between two (or, loosely, several) alternatives, which are or appear equally unfavourable; a position of doubt or perplexity, a ‘fix’.

One of the example sentences is:

> 1888 J. Bryce *Amer. Commonw.* II. liii. 332 They were‥in the dilemma of either violating the Constitution or losing a golden opportunity.

Comment: Though, at least in popular use, *dilemma* can be used when choosing between two *desirable* options as well, as not choosing one of the desirable options could be considered unfavorable.

Comment: @Adam: A dilemma (two-horn) is usually used to describe the choice itself, not the quality of the options. Choosing one is committing to that path and forsaking the other, but both may be equally bad or one may be bad while the other is good. It is "[a situation that requires a choice between options that are or seem equally unfavorable or mutually exclusive.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dilemma)".

Comment: @Robusto: That's my point; the answer states that the options are unappealing.

Comment: It's true that many people use dilemma for a choice in which one or more of the options is not unappealing. However, some of us prefer to restrict *dilemma* to its original meanings (as described in the definitions I posted). One aspect of those meanings is that both options are unappealing; if the word loses that aspect (and I think you're saying that it already has), then I think we've lost a useful word.

Comment: In the Greek language, a problem with one aspect is "problemma", a problem with two aspects is "dilemma", and a problem with three or more aspects is "polilemma". In psychology, a choice between two pleasant things is an approach-approach conflict.

Answer (score 12):

*Pick your poison* seems applicable.

Comment: That's more of a drinking expression though.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен it's certainly used for other purposes, too.

Answer (score 10):

@Phoenix beat me to it:

> You're damned if you do and damned if you don't.

Comment: That's explicitly about choosing between action and inaction, though, whereas the OP wants an expression that could potentially include two equally unpleasant actions.

Comment: If we're to learn from Hamlet, inaction is also an action.

Answer (score 6):

Sophie's choice (after the [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_Choice_%28novel%29) and [movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_Choice_%28film%29) of the same name) is another option, though it tends to imply that the consequences of either choice are *dire*, rather than simply unpleasant or undesirable.

> The cultural impact of the book gave rise to the expression "making a 'Sophie's Choice'", which describes being forced to choose between two very dear possessions; keeping one and losing the other forever. It is a reference to either of the two central choices Sophie made in the book:

Spoilers follow on the Wikipedia pages.

Comment: It was a book before it was a movie.

Answer (score 5):

You may have to choose  either "Lesser of two evils" or "Worse of two evils," or just the evils

Comment: Devils? I know `The lesser of two evils`. Unless you mean the [short film](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0iKQxe3WCw)

Comment: teylyn. Oop. My mistake. It should be 'lesser of two evils.' I was let to hit d before evils by the devil.

Comment: Down in the cotton fields of Carolina, there were a couple of boll weevils. One moved to the big city, got a degree, and had a successful career. His brother stayed on the farm, never amounting to much; he came to be known as the ... *lesser of two weevils*.

Answer (score 3):

This question reminded me of this little historical gem:

> the barbarians drive us to the sea, the sea drives us to the barbarians, between these two means of death we are either killed or drowned.

which, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groans_of_the_Britons), comes from a text called "The Groans of the Britons".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a short phrase that says a little more than just "dilemma", you can go for the [*Cornelian dilemma*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornelian_dilemma).

Answer (score 1):

A few broadly related proverbs (see, e.g., [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/between+the+devil+and+the+deep+blue+sea)):

- In straits
- Between the hammer and the anvil (Hebrew proverb)
- Between two fires
- Catch 22
- Hobson's choice

Comment: I'm not sure that Catch-22 or Hobson's choice apply here. A catch-22 means that each option has the other as a prerequisite, and Hobson's choice is a "false choice", where only one option is really given (the other being to do nothing, rather than having a legitimate second option).

Comment: Indeed, they are not the same but are similar in the sense that there is no real good alternative

Comment: "Between the hammer and the anvil" has nothing to do with choice. It merely means that you are about to be squashed.

Comment: I disagree. Literally, "Between the hammer and the anvil" and "between a rock and a hard place" represent similar situations.

Comment: "Catch 22" isn't about a choice between two bad outcomes. It means that you're already in a bad situation and that, because of a (usually bureaucratic) paradox, you cannot get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

A *false dilemma*.

A dilemma with two options that are both wrong. There is always a third, more reliable option. Sometimes the choices we have are just current states of a situation, and we lack knowledge to see there is really no choice.

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma):

> A false dilemma (also called false dichotomy, black-and/or-white thinking, the either-or fallacy, the fallacy of false choice, the fallacy of exhaustive hypotheses, the fallacy of the false alternative or the fallacy of the excluded middle) is a type of informal fallacy that involves a situation in which limited alternatives are considered, when in fact there is at least one additional option. The opposite of this fallacy is argument to moderation.
>
> The options may be a position that is between two extremes (such as when there are shades of grey) or may be completely different alternatives. Phrasing that implies 2 options (dilemma, dichotomy, black and white) may be substituted with other number-based nouns, such as a "false trilemma" if something is reduced to only 3 options, instead of 2.
>
> False dilemma can arise intentionally, when fallacy is used in an attempt to force a choice (such as, in some contexts, the assertion that "if you are not with us, you are against us"). But the fallacy can also arise simply by accidental omission of additional options rather than by deliberate deception.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a Morton's Fork:

A situation involving having to choose between two equally undesirable outcomes.

Comment: It's the correct answer and it's a pity you didn't provide a source to back it up. However, it was also given by Simchona in her accepted answer http://english.stackexchange.com/a/38244/44619