# Term for situation where alternative choice is not really one

Tags: phrase-requests, expression-choice

What would you call a situation where the current one sucks but you have a 'choice' to an alternative, however the alternative is not really one.

Such as,

> "Sure living in an area under a monopoly internet provider sucks, but
>   you can always live without internet"

Demonstrating an issue where one of the choices isn't really a viable choice or at least comparable alternative.

(There are more dramatic ones)

Comment: Are you looking for a word other than "dilemma," which means a choice between undesirable options?

Comment: well a dilemma is more generic. I think Hobson's choice (phenry's answer) is what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Term for a choice that you like and you dislike?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172639/term-for-a-choice-that-you-like-and-you-dislike). Also [Term for situation where alternative choice is terrible](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199649/), [Proverb or expression for a situation with two choices, both leading to a different kind of trouble](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38243/), and others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers your second link leads back to this question.

Comment: @FizzledOut: We all make mistakes. It looked like there were at least half-a-dozen when I did a Google "site-specific search" for **hobson's choice**, so I just picked the first three. Here's another one to make up for the "interloper": [Expression for a choice which isn't really one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80876/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may be thinking of a [Hobson's choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice):

> A **Hobson's choice** is a free choice in which only one option is offered. As a person may refuse to take that option, the choice is therefore between taking the option or not; "take it or leave it". The phrase is said to originate with Thomas Hobson (1544–1631), a livery stable owner in Cambridge, England. To rotate the use of his horses, he offered customers the choice of either taking the horse in the stall nearest the door or taking none at all.

[Morton's fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton%27s_fork) and [Scylla and Charybdis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis) are related concepts.

Answer (score 15):

You can consider ***the lesser of two evils*** (also ***a lesser evil***).

> the less unpleasant of two choices, neither of which is good:
>
> *But allowing a criminal to go free is perhaps the lesser of two evils if the alternative is imprisoning an innocent person.*
>
> <sup>http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/the-lesser-of-two-evils</sup>

Comment: While that works for saying that you prefer your choice, I wouldn't say it really describes the problem with situation.

Comment: @CobaltHex: You can perfectly fit in your example. "Sure living in an area under a monopoly internet provider is the lesser of two evils if the alternative is living without internet."

Comment: yes, I'm not disagreeing, I just feel like the phrase would be used in a different manner/context. Or at least, it doesn't really describe/emphasize the lack of real choice.

Comment: @CobaltHex: Hobson's choice doesn't indicate your specific situation at all. You have two bad options and one of them is worst than the other. Hobson's choice is about taking an option or not. You can call it "lesser of two evils principle" to indicate the situation better. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesser_of_two_evils_principle

Comment: well I was referring more to hobsons choice, where one of the choices isn't really a viable option

Comment: @CobaltHex: But in your example, you can choose either option. One sucks and other sucks even more but you can still choose either. You were not asking what you meant to ask then.

Answer (score 10):

the most common phrase for this is [*between a rock and a hard place*](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Between-Rock-and-Hard-Place.html):

> Being in a dilemma where the only two available options are both unsatisfying or bad.

The other term is [*dilemma*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dilemma):

> a situation requiring a choice between equally undesirable alternatives.

<sub>Knowyourphrase.com and Dictionary.com</sub>

Comment: I wouldn't really consider them equally undesirable however. (Certainly both bad, but not in the same way)

Comment: @CobaltHex- That sums up ermanen's answer perfectly- both evil, but not equally so, therefore you choose the best of a bad situation.  medica, I upvoted yours as well :-)

Comment: If you go this route, also consider saying that it puts you *in a bind*.

Answer (score 2):

Hugh Rawson, in his book *Unwritten Laws*, considers **Shakespeare's First Law** as an alternative to **Hobson's Choice**.  It comes from *The Taming of the Shrew, (1593-1594)*

> There's small choice in rotten apples

Answer (score 2):

Plenty of alternatives in previous answers, but a modern variation would be a "sophie's choice." [Spoiler Alert] In William Styron's book (and the movie of the same name), the main character, a mother with two young children, is demanded by a Nazi officer to choose which child will go on a train to the camps, in order to preserve her own and the other child's life. (It's a choice she never really recovers from.)

Answer (score 0):

'Up a river without a paddle' I wonder if pluralizing would get this done for you 'Up either river and no paddles'
'Damned if I do damned if I don't'
"Between a rock and a hard place", since both objects or metaphorical choices are rough.
"Between the devil and the deep blue sea"
"Out of the frying pan, into the fire"

http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/up+a+river+without+a+paddle.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilemma

Answer (score 0):

A fine loan-word (from German) that might be useful is [Zugzwang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang) - it refers to a situation in chess where any move a player makes will lead to disaster. The word is reasonably rarely-used but is found in English dictionaries.

Comment: No, that does not really fit. Zugzwang specifically refers to a situation where you HAVE to make a move. The person in the question has a choice.

Answer (score 0):

A situation that sucks and only has terrible alternatives is *a huge [$#1t-sandwich](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shit%20Sandwich)*.

---

> I'm not sure that Catch-22 or Hobson's choice apply here. A catch-22 means that each option has the other as a prerequisite, and Hobson's choice is a "false choice", where only one option is really given (the other being to do nothing, rather than having a legitimate second option). –  Adam Robinson, [-EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38243/proverb-or-expression-for-a-situation-with-two-choices-both-leading-to-a-differ)