# Adjective/noun for a situation that cannot be solved?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, shakespeare

I am writing an essay on Act 3 Scene 5 in *Romeo and Juliet* where the romantic play takes the turn for tragic. Indeed, Juliet loses the support of her primary family and is left deserted, with no hope to turn to except Friar Lawrence.

> There is no room for workarounds around the difficult situation for poor Juliet.

Rather than using the phrase *room for workarounds* or *between a rock and a hard place*, I would have preferred to find a term that suggests this idea of an *untiable knot* (which is clearly not a term). Any suggestions?

This differs from another Stackexchange [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38243/proverb-or-expression-for-a-situation-with-two-choices-both-leading-to-a-differ) since I am not looking for a situation in which there are only two possibilities, but **a situation that cannot be solved**.

Comment: Does 'impasse' cover this? Or is that only appropriate when you're trying to go in one direction and can't go any further?

Comment: Find oneself  *in a corner*, *deadlocked*, *stalemated*, *nowhere to turn*?

Comment: @DavidGarner I think that the context would have to be different for the word 'impasse', but thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @WS2 I doubt that any of the suggested ones fit in correctly e.g. *stalemated - tends to be used for war descriptions* ; *in a corner - I don't really think that that is an appropriate term to use for an extremely formal essay - the same for 'nowhere to turn'* etc.

Comment: @Leuchte, WS2's suggestions are all better than mine!

Comment: @DavidGarner I do indeed agree, but it seems that no word suits what I'm trying to say :(

Comment: Sometimes there just isn't. Shakespeare dealt with this by coining a word.

Comment: @DavidGarner This is (probably) the first time I haven't found a word I wanted in the entirety of the English language! I guess I'll have to use one of these: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/imbroglio

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help, at least I have now got somewhere. Here are some possible impressive terms (although they do not link to complete impossibility): *predicament, imbroglio, quandary*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've edited the question, since it wasn't quite clear what I was after

Comment: Also note that the possible duplicate you suggested was looking for a proverb or expression, not a noun or adjective

Comment: Note that *expression* includes things like nouns and adjectives. Among the suggestions on the earlier question are *dilemma, paradox, double-edged sword, Catch-22, Morton's fork*. And you yourself mentioned *between a rock and a hard place* - I don't see it necessarily makes much difference whether there are exactly *two* "unacceptable" alternatives (as opposed to *many*, or *none*). Also, you say *the **difficult situation** for poor Juliet*, which implies there *is* a "solution" - just not necessarily a desirable one.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is a phrase that means "untiable knot": _a Gordian knot._ However, it's used in the context of "an impossible situation that someone gets out of by cheating or breaking an unwritten rule," since according to legend, Alexander the Great "untied" the impossible knot by cutting it in half with his sword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I will not bandy with thee word for word* ... this dilemma is often referred to as a "double bind".

> **double bind** *noun*:
>
> a situation in which a person is confronted with two irreconcilable demands or a choice between two undesirable courses of action. See, Google.com [**double bind**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=double+bind+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=double+bind+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l3j0i22i30l2.0.0.1.3250025...........0.xEbfLnmmdcE&gws_rd=ssl)

*Do thou but call my resolution wise, And with this knife I’ll help it presently.*

Comment: Thank you, Leuchte. I upvoted you previously. Shame you didn't get more of a response. Did you notice that "**double bind**" wasn't accounted for in the "alleged" duplicate question?